# How to use akka dataflow in maven

Tags: scala, akka, dataflow, continuation

I encountered a problem when using data flow . The maven can not compile if I enable the continuation in maven scala plugin config.

After I enable the continuation in maven, the compile starts to fail. And the error message is very confusing.

Like this:

found   : Unit @scala.util.continuations.cpsSynth @util.continuations.cps[scala.concurrent.Future[Any]]

required: Unit

Or this:

found   : ((Class[_ <: Indexed[String]], scala.concurrent.Promise[List[_ <: Indexed[String]]])) => (Class[*$1(in value $anonfun)], List[* <: Indexed[String]]) @scala.util.continuations.cpsSynth @util.continuations.cps[scala.concurrent.Future[Any]] forSome { type _$1(in value $anonfun) <: Indexed[String] }

required: ((Class[_ <: Indexed[String]], scala.concurrent.Promise[List[_ <: Indexed[String]]])) => B

All these error occurs at the closure . It seems that the closure can not be used in flow context.

Any one knows why ?

Error code:

```
def toList[T <: Indexed[String]](content: Iterable[String], klass: Class[T]) = {
    val ref = new TypeReference[List[T]] {}
    content.flatMap(JsonUtils.toObject(_, ref)).toList
}

flow {
    val objects = toList(content, klass)
    val hasRefs = klass.getFields.filter(it => it.getAnnotation(classOf[Ref]) != null)
    hasRefs.foreach {injectRef(_, objects)}
    promise << objects
}

def injectRef[T <: Indexed[String]](field: Field, objects: List[T]) {
    val anno = field.getAnnotation(classOf[Ref])
    val refKlass = anno.klass()

    def setField(o: T) {
        val original = field.isAccessible
        field.setAccessible(true)
        val f = field.get(o)
        val found = promises.get(refKlass)().find(it => it.index() == f)
        field.set(o, found)
        field.setAccessible(original)
    }
    objects.foreach { o =>
        setField(o) // here, compile error
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some code showing the problem, otherwise it is really difficult to answer meaningfully

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you are still omitting too much: for the compile error to make sense the type of `objects` on that line would need to be `List[(Class[…], Promise[List[…]])]` (simplified), which raises the question what the definition of `toList` is. It seems like your question might be better answered in a different forum (and with full source code). Just to be clear: as long as `T` is just a normal type (no CPS thingy) then it should work. OTOH it is not obvious how your code benefits from dataflow, since it is just the Promise.complete which uses it. (or?)

Comment: oh。 So you suggest me raising this question at the akka mail list? Maybe you are right. I thought it is a simple and common problem, many uses using the dataflow will encounter:)

Comment: If you post it on akka-user please share enough code so that we can compile it ourselves, otherwise it will be difficult to figure out what goes wrong. We can then put the answer in here so that others can find it.